# User validation input under forloop

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String regex = "[a-zA-Z ]+$";
    String regex1 = "\\d[0-9]|[1-9]";
    String regex2 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$";
    String petName;

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    do {
        System.out.print("\nHow Many Pet do you have? Give from 1-3:");
        petName = input.nextLine();

        if (petName.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Number field should not be Empty.");
        } else if (!petName.matches(regex1)) {
            System.out.println("Please Enter A Valid Number!");
        }
    } while (!petName.matches(regex1));

    do {
        Integer.parseInt(petName);
        String[] pets = new String[Integer.parseInt(petName)];

        System.out.print("\nList Down All Your Pet Names:\n");

        for (int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
            System.out.print("\nPET" + (i + 1) + ":");
            pets[i] = input.nextLine();

            if (pets[i].isEmpty()) {
                System.out.print("String field should not be Empty.");
            } else if (!pets[i].matches(regex)) {
                System.out.print("Please input a valid String.");
            }
        }
        output.append("\nThese Are The List Of The Pets You Have:");
        for (int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
            output.append("\nPET:").append(i + 1).append(" ").append(pets);
        }
    } while (!petName.matches(regex));

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

I'm having a little problem with the above codes.

What I want is if I input an integer then it will prompt me this message "Please input a valid String" or if I didn't type anything in the field then it will prompt me this another message "String field should not be Empty". But what happen is even if I type a string value in the field then it's still prompting the message "Please input a valid String" and the loop is still keep doing the same over and over again every time I press enter.

Comment: What is suppose to mean this regex `"[a-zA-Z ]+$"` ? Add some example of input used here.

Comment: for (int i=0; i<pets.length; i++){

            System.out.print("\nPET"+(i+1)+":");
             pets[i]=input.nextLine();

             if  (pets[i].isEmpty())
            System.out.print("String field should not be Empty.");
             else if (!pets[i].matches(regex))
             System.out.print("Please input a valid String.");

I thinnk I'm having trouble with this line here. can you please figure it out for me why?

Comment: that is the code I use to validate the strings.

Comment: if you copy the codes and run it you will understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: Not the code, the input passed through the Scanner. You can't simply past your code and hope someone will do every test case possible. You need to give more information about your problem here (edit the question for that). Espacially without correct indentation ;)

Comment: Oh! I'm sorry I think your having trouble with my very limited english knowlege. I'm not so good at english that's why I just ask you to copy the copy the code and run it nd see for yourself. but thanks anyway I appreciate your motivational speech.

Comment: Well, I did it, I don't have a problem with the checks of values. I do have one with your loops that are wrong but that is not a problem of validation but simple logic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some issues with your second while loop. First of all, your loop condition is checking `petName`, which isn't changed after leaving the first while loop. Second, the for loop seems to be nested incorrectly. Since you want to loop for a valid input of each pet name, you should put the second while loop in the for loop and not the other way around.

It's probably easier to see with the following modified code. Also note that calling `append(pets)` outputs the `toString` result of the `pets` array and not the individual pet name. For this you should use `append(pets[i])`.

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    String regex = "[a-zA-Z ]+$";
    String regex1 = "\\d[0-9]|[1-9]";
    String regex2 = "^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$";
    String petName;

    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    do
    {
        System.out.print("\nHow Many Pet do you have? Give from 1-3:");
        petName = input.nextLine();

        if (petName.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Number field should not be Empty.");
        }
        else if (!petName.matches(regex1))
        {
            System.out.println("Please Enter A Valid Number!");
        }

    } while (!petName.matches(regex1));

    String[] pets = new String[Integer.parseInt(petName)];

    System.out.print("\nList Down All Your Pet Names:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print("\nPET" + (i + 1) + ":");
            pets[i] = input.nextLine();

            if (pets[i].isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.print("String field should not be Empty.");
            }
            else if (!pets[i].matches(regex))
            {
                System.out.print("Please input a valid String.");
            }
        } while (!pets[i].matches(regex));
    }

    output.append("\nThese Are The List Of The Pets You Have:");

    for (int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++)
    {
        output.append("\nPET:").append(i + 1).append(" ").append(pets[i]);
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: I agree with the part of the endless loop. Might just show that part of the code in your answer ;)

Comment: Yahhh! that is the reason why I couldn't come up with my desired output, I've been thinking of that nested while loop but I just don't know how to arrange it, I tried so may arrangement but I couldn't just get it right because I still include this line  String[] pets = new String[Integer.parseInt(petName)]; inside the Do while loop. 

I'm really sorry, you know what it's like for you when you are starting :) . But I really appreciate your immediate assistance and your very kind approach. god, bless you, sir.